# best way to implement production with two consumer

Tags: c#

I need to implement production with two consumers. There is some collection that is shared between the two consumers and both of them wait until the production will add something to this collection.

I think using BlockingCollection is the best way - and use the BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable() to track on the shared collection on both consumer.

Comment: What are the active classes, the producer? or the consumers?

Comment: the application hold 3 main thread - two off the consumers and on on the producer. all of them are active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `ReactiveExtensions`

[A Playful Introduction to Rx by Erik Meijer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKore-AkisY)

[Intro to Rx by Lee Campbell](http://www.introtorx.com/)

**Example** *taken from [codePERFdotNET](http://codeperf.net/rx-request-response-throttle/)*

```
// Or whatever producer you have, expose an IObservable
public interface IApiService 
{
    IObservable<Response> Responses { get; }
}
```

Then you can subscribe to that Observable multiple times:

```
    public Controller(IApiService service)
    {
        // Do one thing for each response
        service.Responses
            .Subscribe(responseHandler);

        // Do something else for each response
        service.Responses
            .Subscribe(r => _throttle.OnNext(0));
    }
```

**EDIT**

It's not clear if you want both consumers to handle each message or distribution using a queuing system where multiple threads read off of a queue which has work to process, and each piece of work is only handled by 1 consumer. If so either look at enterprise messaging solution such as [MSMQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) or any other MQ system out there. If it is internal to your app only then use something like [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)